# How to make an MQ app exe to run continously?

Tags: .net, windows-services, ibm-mq

I have wrote an MQ app, which is exe, but it only runs for a single instance and terminates itself. The desired functionality is to have it running continuously and keep processing the data and once the data is exhausted, it should keep listening for the new data.

May some one please suggest me what needs to be done?

Thanks!

Comment: is this question about IBM MQ or custom messaging queue?

Answer (score 5):

Currently your application probably loops through messages until it gets back a return code indicating that the queue is empty.  In order to keep listening for new data, you need to do two things:

1. Don't exit the loop when you get back a return code for "empty queue."  Loop around and attempt another `Receive()`.  You **must** combine this with the next recommendation though.
2. When you perform the `Receive()` do so using a time-out.  For example, `consumer.Receive(20000)` will wait 20 seconds for the next message before timing out.

If you do not include the timeout, then the application will throw massive numbers of unsatisfied GET requests at the QMgr which will appear to be a runaway app and/or a runaway QMgr and you will see processes with high CPU utilization.

You could sleep between `Receive()` calls but this is not very performant.  Using a `Receive(TIMEOUT)` blocks the thread only while no messages are available.  As soon as a message arrives, there is no delay in passing it to the thread.  If you manually sleep the thread, it must poll the queue and will only do so at set `sleep()` intervals.

The alternative is that you can set up a callback method so that the thread doesn't block.  For example, if you have a callback method `OnNewMessageCallback` you can create an async message listener with `MessageListener messageListener = new MessageListener(OnNewMessageCallback);`

Both of these methods are described in the samples. If you installed the SDK and samples, these will be under `C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ\tools\dotnet\samples` or the equivalent, depending on where you installed WMQ.

In case you are wondering how to tell the difference between "no message on queue" and some more serious error, check the `MQException.ReasonCode`.  If it is 2033, then the `Receive()` timed out.  That and all the other reason codes are defined [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r1/topic/com.ibm.mq.doc/fc_MQRC_.htm).

Once you have a program that will successfully loop around and wait for new messages, then you can either choose to run it as a service as described in Simon's response, or interactively as you do now.

If you are developing on WMQ v6 please be aware that v6 is end-of-service as of September 2012 and that the .Net integration is *much* better in v7.0 or v7.1 of WMQ.  You can download the latest WMQ v7.0 client with .Net classes from [SupportPac MQC7](http://ibm.co/SupptPacMQC7).  The corresponding Infocenter is [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.mq.csqzav.doc/un10120_.htm).  The v7.1 client will be a [SupportPac](http://ibm.co/SupptPacs) when it is released, but the exact name is not yet known.  I'll try to remember to update this with a link when it is available.  As of today, the v7.1 client is available through Passport Advantage using your IBM customer account.  The v7.1 Infocenter is [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r1/topic/com.ibm.mq.doc/un10690_.htm).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you transform your code into a Windows Service. See here for a .NET starter: [Introduction to Windows Service Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d56de412%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using .NET interface then look at IBM Message Service Client for .NET a.k.a XMS .NET also. XMS .NET provides a JMS like API but in a .NET language. It has a message listener through which messages can be received asynchronously.

XMS gets installed as part of MQ v7 Client SupportPac MQC7.